# Possibly convoluted sentence, but is it correct?

Tags: british-english, writing-style, writing

I saw this sentence in an email — is it actually correct?

> In light of the time and effort you have spent and may otherwise continue to spend on dealing with their repeated requests for assistance, we’ll offer them a $50 assistance for the forthcoming term should the requirements be agreed."

Is it convoluted?

Comment: Yes, it's correct (although I'd want to add *upon* at the very end).  Yes it's more complex than typical conversational sentences.

Comment: @Jim It's not recommended to end a sentence with a preposition - right?

Comment: ... Ending a sentence with a preposition is rarely advised against nowadays, and far better than most rewrites in many cases.

Comment: Understand that all bare "is this correct?" questions are off-topic proofreading.

Comment: Never end a sentence with preposition?  Says who?  What were they thinking of?  That's an old style prohibition that can be idiomatically violated.

Comment: @WKleinberg I recommend you put the source of your concern in the question.  People are starting to close the question as a proof reading question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Don't you mean *Nowadays ending a sentence with a preposition is rarely advised against*?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, it is quite complicated, and it is, technically, correct although it could be simplified. "That" could be inserted before "you" to clarify that the dependent clause is continued, and "upon" could, also, be inserted after "agreed."

Answer (score 0):

It's grammatically sound, but the long adverbial clause of reason is difficult to digest. Would you consider shortening it?